# Display hierarchy of the terms for the current post (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I am trying to display a hierarchy of the terms for the current post in Wordpress like this :

```
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'type' );
    if($terms) {
        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
            $term_parent = get_term_by("id", $term->parent, "type");
            $parent_term_link = get_term_link( $term_parent );
            if ($term->parent > 0) {
                echo '<a href="'. $parent_term_link .'">'. $term_parent->name . '</a> ';
            }
            // for the children now
            $children_terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'type');
            if($children_terms) {
                foreach ( $children_terms as $children_term ) {
                    echo '<pre>';
                    var_dump($children_term);
                    echo '</pre>';
                    if ( $children_term->parent === $term_parent->term_id ) {
                        echo $term->name;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I quite dit it but I got this error in return :

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /web/wp-content/themes/make-child/partials/entry-meta-post-footer.php on line 25

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /web/wp-content/themes/make-child/partials/entry-meta-post-footer.php on line 25
```

for the line 25 :

```
if ( $children_term->parent === $term_parent->term_id ) {
```

How can I avoid this error message (even if it returns the good result) ?

Here's what the var_dump is returning :

```
object(WP_Term)#3205 (11) {
  ["term_id"]=>
  int(39)
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "#10"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["term_group"]=>
  int(0)
  ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
  int(39)
  ["taxonomy"]=>
  string(4) "type"
  ["description"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["parent"]=>
  int(25)
  ["count"]=>
  int(2)
  ["filter"]=>
  string(3) "raw"
  ["object_id"]=>
  int(44)
}

(good result between)

object(WP_Term)#3205 (11) {
  ["term_id"]=>
  int(39)
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "#10"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["term_group"]=>
  int(0)
  ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
  int(39)
  ["taxonomy"]=>
  string(4) "type"
  ["description"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["parent"]=>
  int(25)
  ["count"]=>
  int(2)
  ["filter"]=>
  string(3) "raw"
  ["object_id"]=>
  int(44)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I must add that I have the good values in return + the error message

Comment: please write complete warning message.

Comment: Print `$children_term` variable in loop and add that array into your question.

Comment: Ok, thans for your attention Milap, I did it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I've found what I was searching for here :
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-hierarchical-taxonomy-list#post-3881067

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'category'; // change this to your taxonomy
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( "fields" => "ids" ) );
if( $terms ) {
  echo '<ul>';

  $terms = trim( implode( ',', (array) $terms ), ' ,' );
  wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $terms );

  echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```